# Update Magento2 version 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 problem

Tags: magento, composer-php, version, magento2

i am trying to update Magento with the following steps

1. composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update on composer.json archive.
2. run composer update

And i have these problems

**Problem 1**

*- magento/project-enterprise-edition is present at version 2.4.2 and cannot be modified by Composer*

*- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 requires vertexinc/product-magento-module-commerce 4.2.1 -> satisfiable by vertexinc/product-magento-module-commerce[4.2.1].*

*- vertexinc/product-magento-module-commerce[4.2.1] cannot be installed as that would require removing magento/project-enterprise-edition[2.4.2]. They both replace vertex/product-magento-module-commerce and thus cannot coexist.*

*- Root composer.json requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.3].*

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first glance I'd say that while you do the `composer require --no-update [--] magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3` explicitly not doing any updates, the original Magento Enterprise Edition is kept locked to version 2.4.2.

Then running `composer update` is not updating it, resulting into the foremost problem reported (it looks leading to me, that all other problems are caused by it):

> `magento/project-enterprise-edition` is present at version `2.4.2` and cannot be modified by Composer

It is my own understanding that the reason it *cannot be modified by Composer* is because `magento/project-enterprise-edition` is ***locked*** to `2.4.2`.

Try running:

```bash
composer update magento/project-enterprise-edition
```

to update that package explicitly.

(I can't say - as you did not share in your question - why you did run the `composer require` with `--no-update`, it is just that with `--no-update` the  lock file is not updated and it seems that it is in use and further on pinning `magento/project-enterprise-edition` to [previous!] version `2.4.2` - you want to ***update*** to `2.4.3` [!]).

Additionally, running

- `composer update --with-dependencies magento/project-enterprise-edition` or
- `composer update --with-all-dependencies magento/project-enterprise-edition`

may be useful to escalate follow-up issues to make the dependency update command more binding. Excerpt from `composer update --help` *(Composer version 2.1.11 2021-11-02 12:10:2)*:

> - `-w`, `--update-with-dependencies`: Allows inherited dependencies to be updated, except those that are root requirements.
> - `-W`, `--update-with-all-dependencies`: Allows all inherited dependencies to be updated, including those that are root requirements.

Root requirements are those in your `composer.{json,lock}` file.